# Spring Boot+Thymeleaf each+if

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

from Backend Java, I have a Map like this:
Map allMenus
This map has already contained these object:
1. allMenus
2. subMenus
Their details are:

```
{subMenu=[MenuItem [id=3, itemCaption=sub menu 1-1, itemUrl=http://www.google.com.tw, itemParentId=1, itemOrder=1], MenuItem [id=4, itemCaption=sub menu 1-2, itemUrl=http://tw.yahoo.com, itemParentId=1, itemOrder=2], MenuItem [id=5, itemCaption=sub menu 2-1, itemUrl=http://tw.msn.com, itemParentId=2, itemOrder=1], MenuItem [id=6, itemCaption=sub menu 2-2, itemUrl=https://www.hosting24.com/, itemParentId=2, itemOrder=2], MenuItem [id=7, itemCaption=sub menu 2-3, itemUrl=http://u.camdemy.com/, itemParentId=2, itemOrder=3]], rootMenu=[MenuItem [id=1, itemCaption=top menu 1, itemUrl=null, itemParentId=0, itemOrder=1], MenuItem [id=2, itemCaption=top menu 2, itemUrl=null, itemParentId=0, itemOrder=2]]}
```

Now, in the Front-end HTML:
I use the following codes to form a SideBar,
which contains Top Menu and Sub Menu, total levels = 2, but failed.
Please read my codes:

```
<nav id="sidebar">
    <div style="height: 100px;"></div>
    <div th:each="rootMenu:${allMenus.rootMenu}">
            <button type="button" id="btn-sidebar" class="btn btn-warning"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu1sub1"
                th:text="${rootMenu.itemCaption}"></button>
                <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1">
                    <ul th:each="subMenu:${allMenus.subMenu}">
                        <li class="nav-item" th:if="${subMenu.itemParentId == rootMenu.id}">
                            <a th:href="${subMenu.itemUrl}" th:text="${subMenu.itemCaption}"
                            ></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The result of the above codes are:
1. All top menus are correctly shown.
2. However, sub menus are all put in the first top menu, which is wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07XyP.png)

Comment: So "sub menu 1-2" should be under menu 2?

Comment: I could not find any errors in the code except duplicate id's inside the loop.. when you are iterating please avoid static id's inside the loop.. try to use classes or dynamic Id's..

Comment: Sub menu 1-1, 1-2 are all placed under top menu 1. Nothing is placed under top menu 2 now. Besides, Sub menu 2-1 should be under top menu 2.